# How extract objects and their size in border of continuous images from line-scan camera using OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, object, camera

I want to extract total number of objects and their size based on **OpenCV** and **Python**.
I assume that tiny objects moves irregularly on the conveyor belt. Since objects size is important for me, I decide to use a **line scan camera** to store images.

Line scan cameras usually store the received data in the form of consecutive images which each image have a certain number of scanned lines.

**Problem:**

I can extract objects that are completely in an image and compute their size. My **main problem** is extracting the number and size of objects that are in the **margin/border** of two consecutive images.

Here is an **example** of consecutive images (*image n* and *image n+1*). The red lines show the **margin/border** of consecutive images.

[example images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9735W.png)

What is the solution to overcome this problem? Can you suggest methods for this problem?

Best Regards,

Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

To analyze page n, first concatenate page n-1, n, n+1 and detect all objects in this 3-page image. The detection algorithm might fail for objects at the top and bottom edge but objects relevant to page n should be detected just fine. For each object, determine the y position within the 3-page image (e.g. the lowest y pixel of the object, or the center of mass of the object). All objects that have a y position between 1/3 and 2/3 of the page belong to page n (assuming each page has the same height). Now do the same for the next page.

Note that this approach analyzes each page 3x. You can try and reduce the overhead once you have this working. For example if you know that objects are always shorter than 100 pixels, you could limit the concatenation to the bottom 100 pixels of page n-1 and top 100 pixels of page n+1.

Comment: At first, I shall thank you for your idea and help. I designed my code based on your suggestion and it works fine. As you mentioned, this approach analyzes each page 3x. For reducing overhead, is there any method to find incomplete objects which are at the top margin/border of page n? If yes, first, we find complete objects of page n. Then, we find and save the top portion of page n (t_p_p_n) which includes incomplete objects. Finally, we concatenation this portion (t_p_p_n) and page n+1 to find complete objects. I think this approach can reduce overhead.